# Is there a method to determine if $\sin(b)$ is positive or negative?

Tags: trigonometry, numerical-methods

Is there a method to determine if $\sin(b)$, where $b \in \Bbb R$, is positive or negative?

I am trying to approximate $\pi$ using the Intermediate Value Theorem, $\pi$ is obviously between $3$ and $4$ but to be more precise, I need to know if $\pi$ is on the left of the mid point of $3$ and $4$ or right of it. Thus I need to know if $\sin(3.5)$ is positive or negative. I am asking for $\sin(b)$ in general.

Comment: What is IVT ?...

Comment: I think, there is no better method than to reduce $b$ modulo $2\pi$. The Taylor series converges too slow for large $x$ to give a more efficient method.

Comment: Intermediate value theorem @JeanMarie

Comment: All the usual methods of numerically computing the sine rely on reducing the argument by multiples or fractions of pi, so that a polynomial approximation is only required for $[0,\frac\pi4]$. Meaning your goal is circular, you could just as well print out the pi constant of your library. What can be sensibly done is to solve $\sin(\frac\pi6)=\frac12$.

Comment: And if you say IVT as a method, you probably mean the bisection method. Check out the other bracketing root-finding methods.

Comment: This may help: $\pi = 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067...$

Comment: @coudy Is it a joke ? If yes, I don't understand it ;)

Comment: Yes it is a joke. I don't really understand the question. One has to check if $b$ belongs to an interval of the form $]2k\pi , \pi+2k\pi[$ for some $k$. So it seems to be about computing $\pi$ with sufficient accuracy?

Comment: Instead of staying around $\pi$, I advise you to concentrate on approximating $\pi/4$ which is in calm waters in the mid of the quarter unit circle in the first quadrant and try to have $\tan x$ the closest to $1$. This can be done by managing not a value $x_n$ but a vector $a_n, b_n$ with $x_n=a_/b_n$: this is in fact a particular case of a method called CORDIC.

Comment: One can also reduce the angle using the double-angle trigononometric identities. Then compute sine and cosine of $x=2^{-n}b$ via the series with sufficient accuracy, then restore the wanted values by iteratively doubling the angle. This trigonometric squaring also loses accuracy, so there is some balance to consider in how large $n$ is taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a method to determine the sign of $\sin(x)$ for any $x$, but it is not simple to implement using finite precision arithmetics.

In **exact** arithmetic the problem can be reduced trivially to the case of $x \in [0, 2 \pi)$ because $x \rightarrow \sin(x)$ is $2\pi$ periodic. Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ be given. Compute $$k = \left \lfloor \frac{x}{2 \pi} \right \rfloor.$$ Then $$0 \leq r = x - 2 k \pi < 2 \pi$$ and $$x = 2 k \pi + r.$$ It follows that $$\sin(x) = \sin(r).$$ The transformation from $x$ to $r$ is an example of *range reduction*. In practice it is difficult to reduce the range even in this very special case. When $x$ is very large, then the subtraction$$ r  = x - 2k \pi$$ will almost certainly cancel catastrophically and $r$ will be computed with a large relative error. This is a significant issue especially if the true value of $r$ is nearly $\pi$. There is a cure, but it requires us to compute $r$ using extended precision or by simulating a smaller unit roundoff. This is not entirely trivial. The interval $[0, 2\pi)$ can be reduced further by exploiting the symmetries of the function $x \rightarrow \sin(x)$, but the fundamental problem of computing $r$ accurately remains.

Is there a simpler method that will allow you to compute $\pi$ provided that you have a good implementation of the function $x \rightarrow \sin(x)$? Yes. You can execute the functional iteration
$$x_{n+1} = x_n + \sin(x_n)$$
starting with say $x_0 = 3$. This iteration has cubic convergence.

There are two very good books that you might find interesting. They are

1. Jean-Michel Muller: "Elementary functions: Algorithms and implementation". [Link to Springer's page](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4899-7983-4)
2. Jean-Michel Mueller et. al: "Handbook of Floating-Point Arithmetic". [Link to Springer's page](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-8176-4705-6)